# Error on POST Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am developing in Laravel 5.3.

When reviewing the routes, I have the following:

[image: Routers]

Here it indicates that my routes are POST. But if in Postman I enter the URL (POST), I throw the following error

[image]

The strangest thing is that on my local server it works fine, this error occurred to me on the production server.

My code is:

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api']], function() {
require_once 'Routes/Api/ProductRoute.php';
```

});

**routes/Routes/Api/UserRoute.php**

```
<?php

Route::post('user/authenticate', [
    'as' => 'api.user.authenticate',
    'uses' => 'Api\UserController@authenticate'
]);

Route::post('user/register', [
    'as' => 'api.user.register',
    'uses' => 'Api\UserController@register'
]);
```

**/app/Http/Controllers/Api/UserController.php**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            \DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')
                ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->where('name', $request->platform)
                ->update(['revoked' => 1]);

            $token = $user->createToken($request->platform)->accessToken;
            return Controller::apiResponse(1, compact('user', 'token'));
        } else{
            return Controller::apiResponse(-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can't really help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I added my code

Comment: The routes in your screenshot aren't the routes in your code...

Comment: @ceejayoz I had copied the wrong route, edited and copied the correct. In api.php I have included the file UserRoute.php

Comment: Are your routes cached? Try running `php artisan route:clear` on your production machine and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: @EricTucker i run the command, but the problem persist